# Sharing using facebook with Laravel Socialize

Tags: laravel, facebook-php-sdk

is it possible to use Socialize plugin to share content (PHP not JS)?
in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.  Socialize just logs you in.  It will return a token.  You then use that token to log a user into the Facebook api.

Comment: so, do you know someplace or tutorial that I can use to integrate facebook PHP SDK into laravel?